# Obtener dato de mongoose.findOne();

Tags: express, mongoose

¿Qué tal? Tengo un problema, necesito conseguir de la base de datos MongoDB un email (ya existente) para luego compararlo con el que me da el usuario y asi poder devolverle si el email esta usado o no. El problema viene de que declaro el siguiente metodo pero no se como guardar el resultado para compararlo fuera de la variable.

```
var emailValidator = User.findOne({email : req.body.email}, function(err, User){
    if(err){console.log(String(err))};
    return User;
});
```

Mi idea era despues poner un if, en donde comparo el resultado de emailValidator con el email que me da el usuario, quiza no es la forma mas adecuada, ya buscare una mejor, pero no puedo hacer que emailValidator me devuelva el email de la base de datos, ya que me devuelve el objeto del metodo findOne();. Si alguien me podria ayudar estaria muy agradecido. (La coneccion a la DB esta bien hecha, puedo guardar usuarios sin problemas) Gracias.

Comment: Estás usando una función [`callback`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Glossary/Callback_function), por lo tanto toda la lógica de validación la debes incluir dentro de dicha función. La asignación que realizas a `emailValidator` te devuelve un Objeto tipo [`Query`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/query.html). Por otra parte, si tu modelo se llama `User`, no es buena práctica llamar al documento devuelto por la consulta con el mismo nombre. Una forma de diferenciarlos sería usar sólo minúsculas: `user`. Saludos

Comment: Ya cambie lo de user y termine encontrando que existe mongoose-unique-validator un plugin que solamente tenes que agregarle la propiedad   
var user_Schema = new Schema({
    email : {type : String, required : true, unique : true},                            });     Y ya estaba, asi que lo resolvi por ahi. Muchisimas gracias

Comment: Me alegra que lo hayas resuelto. Dicho plugin es muy sencillo de usar la verdad. Aunque yo prefiero no llenar tanto mis dependencias. Puedes crear tu propio *UniqueErrorHandler* en el esquema de Mongoose. Recuerda que la opción `unique` no es un validador. Puedes leer [The unique Option is Not a Validator](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/validation.html#the-unique-option-is-not-a-validator) en la documentación. Si te aventuras a realizar tu propia función de validación sobre el esquema, te dará una visión mucho más amplia del proceso subyacente. Saludos

Comment: Si, entiendo lo de hacer mi validador en el Schema, el tema es que todavia me cuesta mucho, pero de a poquito estoy aprendiendo, muchas gracias por tu ayuda y el tiempo dedicado, voy a leer lo que me dejaste :)